# PHP 5.6 SSL certification with Zend Framework 1.11 for IMAP connection fails GMAIL

Tags: php, email, ssl, zend-framework, imap

I've written a php file which retrieves E-Mails from a GMail Account through IMAP. It uses Zend Framework Version 1.11. First it worked when I was using PHP 5.5.59 in my test environment. After upgrading to PHP 5.6 (the version on the production environment) the code breaks with a Zend Exception. The following code is used to set up the connection to a GMail Account with SSL:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host' => 'imap.gmail.com',
'port' => '993',
'user' => 'xxxxxxx',
'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
'folder' => 'INBOX',
'ssl' => 'SSL')
);
```

The exception I get is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception'
> with message 'cannot connect to host; error =  (errno = 0 )' in
> Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php:100 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php(273): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap->connect('sslin.df.eu', '993', 'SSL')
>
> ## 1 zendtest.php(28): Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap->__construct(Array)
>
> ## 2 {main}   thrown in Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php on line 100

I've tried to download a ca-bundle from this url http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem following the advice of this forum http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=7440&title=Problem_with_SSL_and_PHP_5.6 and installed it however it still gives me the same aforementioned error.

Allow less secure apps is enabled for the GMail Account. That's why it worked with PHP 5.5.59.

Any ideas where I could get a valid certificate and how I have to use it with PHP 5.6 and Zend Framework 1.11?